# Magento 2 trigger product custom tab to open on click

Tags: products, magento-2.1.7, tabs

I would like to trigger click on custom tab from another source.
E.g. **Be the first to review this product** anchor.

This triggers the reviews tab to open. How to achieve this with a custom tab or any other default tab ?

Thanks.

Comment: colud you please little elaborate more ?

Comment: Ok , So in the product page you have a link that says: Be the first to review this product, this link opens the review tab. what I would like to do is add a new link just bellow that and on click open my custom tab.

Comment: okay , there is custom tab next to review tab...and you want to open that with a custom  link , placed  below review link ?

Comment: @ Manoj Deswal You got it! how could one achieve this ?

Comment: if you have live URL then I can tell you the right place to do it , other wise I can guide you for LUMA

Comment: @ Manoj Deswal  No it's in test at the moment ! why do you need live url anyway? it a simple thing to do without Magento platform but I would like to know if there are any default option available to accomplish this task.

Comment: no , do it simple way... I also need to check the tab id to open on click ..nothing else ..just pass the tab id ..it will open smoothly

Comment: Yeap Already tried that it didn't work!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66703/discussion-between-manoj-deswal-and-juliano-vargas).

Comment: check the URL when you click on link...where it redirects , it should go to the ID passed in anchor tag